# Как объединить 60000 файлов в один файл?

Tags: bash, unix, объединение

В директории есть порядка 60000 текстовых файлов, их надо объединить в один файл.

Команда:

```
cat * > all.txt
```

не срабатывает:

```
-bash: /bin/cat: Argument list too long
```

Попробовал через:

```
find ./ -name '*.txt' | xargs grep '' > ../all.txt
```

но столкнулся с тем, что в `all.txt` записывается и путь, и название файла:

```
.//file1.txt:row1
.//file1.txt:row2
...
```

Какие еще могут быть варианты?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
touch ../all.txt
find ./ -name "*.txt" | xargs cat >> ../all.txt
```

То есть `cat` каждого файла по отдельности, а не сразу всех в одной команде cat.

Answer (score 0):

воспроизводим ситуацию (у меня получилось с чуть большим количеством файлов):

```
$ for i in $(seq 1 600000); do echo $i > $i.txt; done
$ ls | wc -l
600000
$ cat *.txt > spisok
bash: /bin/cat: Argument list too long
```

будем добавлять содержимое в файл, который не подпадает под маску `*.txt` — это полезное условие, которое помогает избежать некоторых неприятностей.

очень быстро и наиболее оптимально, вероятно, сделать примерно так (`wc -l файл` — это подсчёт количества строк в файле):

```
$ find -name \*.txt -exec cat {} > spisok +
$ wc -l spisok
600000 spisok
$ head -n 3 spisok
200784
59591
584250
```

хм. файлы читались явно не по алфавитном порядку.

если так не пойдёт, то придётся применить менее оптимальное решение с сортировкой и командой `xargs`:

```
$ find -name \*.txt | sort | xargs -I{} cat {} > spisok
$ wc -l spisok
600000 spisok
$ head -n 3 spisok
100000
100001
100002
```

теперь файлы читаются (и записываются) по (алфавитному) порядку.

Comment: Хм :) О порядке разговор не стоял изначально, но думаю, что в общем случае он будет нужен. А как реализовать вариант сортировать только по значению "*" (т.е. 1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,100001... в примере)?

Comment: по значению — вероятно, подразуемеваете числовую сортировку. для начала надо избавиться от префикса `./`, который добавляет `find`, а потом использовать опцию `-n` у программы `sort`. например, так: `find -name \*.txt -printf '%P\n' | sort -n | head -n 1` возвратит строку `1.txt`

Comment: а порядок `1.txt,10.txt,100.txt...` — это и не алфавитный и не числовой, а какой-то «кастомный». это не в *ms/windows* ли, случайно, так файлы в каталоге сортируются?

Comment: Это лексикографический порядок по имени файла без расширения. Да, Windows.

Comment: поискал. у `ls` есть похожая сортировка —  с опцией `-v natural sort of (version) numbers within text`. у `sort` она называется по-другому: `-g Sort numerically, converting a prefix of each line to a long double-precision floating point number`. это только в операционной системе *gnu* реализовано, а в стандарт *posix* не входит: см. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ls.html и http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sort.html